# Kendo UI difficulty getting Errors from grid model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

In a Kendo UI grid I have an InLine edit which I am validating server side and if errors exist I return them in the json. I have gotten this far, but I am struggling to pull those errors out of the object to handle them.   I will put in the code below starting with the problem and working backward.

I am grabbing the model from the Edit event. The model is populated, I can see the errors in the console, but the value of my errors variable in the below is null.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var errors = e.model.Errors;
    console.log(errors);
    console.log(e.model);
};
```

Here is my cshtml grid setup where I configure the Edit event and editable code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RosterGridViewModel>()
    .Name(gridId)
    .HtmlAttributes(new {style="height: 400px;"})
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ApprovalStatus);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Birthdate).Format("{0:M/dd/yyyy}");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Uic).Title("UIC");
        columns.Bound(p => p.DateAdded).Format("{0:M/dd/yyyy}");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(190);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound").Edit("onEdit"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .Read(o => o.Action(AppRoute.RosterGridRead.ToMethod(), AppRoute.RosterGridRead.ToController()))
        .Update(o => o.Action(AppRoute.RosterEdit.ToMethod(), AppRoute.RosterEdit.ToController()))
        .Destroy(o => o.Action(AppRoute.RosterGridDestroy.ToMethod(), AppRoute.RosterGridDestroy.ToController()))
        .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.School))
        .Model(model => 
            {
                model.Id(p => p.Id);
                model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.ApprovalStatus).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.DateAdded).Editable(false);
            }
        )
    )
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Custom().Text(ActionLabel.DeleteSelection.GetDescription()).HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "deleteSelection(event)" }))
)
```

[image: Below is an image of the model object.]

Comment: I tried switching "Errors" to be "ValidationErrors" and I switched the event to Save instead of Edit.  Symptoms unchanged...the quest goes on.

Comment: which object is logged in your console/image you're showing?

Comment: The object shown is the e.model variable shown in the first code block.

Comment: WORKAROUND INFORMATION:   I never truly solved this issue to my satisfaction.  dcodesmith sent me down the correct path.  In order to get the errors so that I could use them I had to loop over the grid rows and check each for any error messages in the data.  I did this in the DataBound event though I think it would have worked in the edit or save events I was originally attempting to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the `e.model.Errors` object to `JSON` first as shown below and then you can grab any property/key you need.

```
e.model.Errors.toJSON().Message
```

Comment: e.model.Errors is returning as null even though you can see the values contained in it when looking at e.model.  So e.model.Errors.toJSON() throws the error that "e.model.Errors" is null.

Comment: It shows Errors as NULL when I do it this way!   Not sure why, but it gives me something new to look into.  Thanks!